# Variable type long not receiving value?

Tags: vba, excel

So, I am trying to get a piece of code to set some axes values based on a variable input, and I thought this was something super easy, but... In this code below, the variable iFlatMax only ever equals zero, not the values I tell it to equal in the `If` statement.  What gives?  `iCamType` is set in another `Sub()`

```
Private Sub PlotResults()

Dim wbNew As Workbook
Dim iRegSamples As Long
Dim iColumnStart As Long
Dim sXValues As String
Dim sYValues As String
Dim iToeMin, iToeMax, iFlatMin, iFlatMax As Long

'Set axes values based on cam type
If iCamType = 93 Then
    iToeMin = -0.02
    iToeMax = 0
    iFlatMin = -0.015
    iFlatMax = 0.025
Else
    iToeMin = -0.01
    iToeMax = 0.01
    iFlatMin = -0.01
    iFlatMax = 0.015
End If

'More code

End Sub
```

Comment: You'll want to use `single` or `double` types for your Toe/Flat variables, not `long`. Here's a post on the `single` data type from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xay7978z.aspx

Comment: 1) `Dim iToeMin, iToeMax, iFlatMin, iFlatMax As Long` - only `iFlatMax` has type `Long` while `iToeMin, iToeMax, iFlatMin` all `Variant`. 2) `Long` can't hold decimal numbers. Use `Double` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
Dim iToeMin, iToeMax, iFlatMin, iFlatMax As Long
```

to:

```
Dim iToeMin as Double, iToeMax as Double, iFlatMin as Double, iFlatMax As Double
```